# Loop output to list. Is there an elegant alternative?

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse

In order to get the accuracy values from a forecast output vs. actual values in long format with many models and id's, I wanted to loop through the data and iteratively reduce the input object by using tail(input_object, -Forecast_horizon).

I would rather prefer some tidy approach to do this, because looping like this seems odd and crude.

```
library(forecast)
library(tibble)
testing_frame <- tibble(.value = rep(c(11,32,35,57,67,34),12),
                            test_value = rep(c(12,33,40,60,69,44),12),
                        id = rep(as.factor(c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6),rep(4,6),rep(5,6),rep(6,6))),2),
                        model = as.character(c(rep(1,36),c(rep(2,36)))))

H = 6
iter = c(1:12)
datalist = list()
i = 1

for (i in iter) {
    acc_all = forecast::accuracy(ts(head(testing_frame$.value,frequency = H),n=H),
                                 ts(head(testing_frame$test_value,frequency = H),n=H))
    testing_frame <- tail(testing_frame, -H)
    acc_all_out = acc_all[,7]
    datalist[[i]] <- acc_all_out 
}
output = do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

Comment: You are not iterating over anything.  Iter = 12.  So i in iter evaluates to a single number.  Perhaps you meant to define `iter = c(1:12)` and then your opening line of loop should be `for (i in seq_along(iter)) {`

Comment: Thanks, I should know better! Just corrected my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat more succint approach would be to use data frame unpacking in
`summarise()` to create new columns for each metric returned by `accuracy()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)

testing_frame %>% 
  group_by(id, model) %>% 
  summarise(
    accuracy(
      ts(.value, frequency = H),
      ts(test_value, frequency = H)
    ) %>% as_tibble()
  )
#> # A tibble: 12 x 9
#> # Groups:   id [6]
#>    id    model    ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE   ACF1 `Theil's U`
#>    <fct> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 1     1      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  2 1     2      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  3 2     1      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  4 2     2      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  5 3     1      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  6 3     2      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  7 4     1      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  8 4     2      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#>  9 5     1      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#> 10 5     2      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#> 11 6     1      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
#> 12 6     2      3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
```

Comment: I did not know, about this capability of summarise. Pretty neat!

Comment: much better - thanks Mikko

Answer (score 1):

There is no variation across id/model, in terms of .value/test_value, so the output is the same for each iteration. However, presumably your actual data has this variation. Below is an approach that groups by id and model (i.e. 12 groups), and then uses `nest()`, `map()` , and `unnest_wider()` to get your result

```
testing_frame %>% group_by(id, model) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(acc = map(data,~accuracy(ts(.x$.value, frequency = H),ts(.x$test_value,frequency=H)))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(acc) %>% 
  rename_all(~c("id","model", "data","ME","RMSE","MAE","MPE","MAPE","ACF1", "Theil's U"))
```

Output:

```
   id    model data                ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE   ACF1 `Theil's U`
   <fct> <chr> <list>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 1     1     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 2 2     1     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 3 3     1     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 4 4     1     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 5 5     1     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 6 6     1     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 7 1     2     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 8 2     2     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
 9 3     2     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
10 4     2     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
11 5     2     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
12 6     2     <tibble [6 x 2]>  3.67  4.83  3.67  9.08  9.08 -0.114       0.128
```

Comment: Thanks! I will dig a bit more into map and nest. Seems worth it